# How to match javascript variable within an XSL loop up and display matched record

Tags: variables, xslt, search, match

Here's my XSL

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<document>
 <metadata>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">key1</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">link111</field> 
 </metadata> 
 <metadata> 
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">key2</field> 
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">link222</field> 
 </metadata> 
 <metadata> 
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords">key3</field>
  <field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url">link333</field> 
 </metadata> 
</document>
```

Here's my code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" >
<![CDATA[
var pass_js_variable = "key2";
]]>
</xsl:text>
</script>

Match Keywords:
<xsl:for-each select="document/metadata[field[@name = 'MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords' and contains(.,$pass_js_variable)]]">
    Page URL: <xsl:value-of select="field[@name = 'MyWebsite/Metadata/active_url']"/>
</xsl:for-each> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results:
If **$pass_js_variable** matches any of "**field name="MyWebsite/Metadata/Keywords**", then display active_url from xml.

... but my code is not working... any idea?

Comment: Your CDATA block will be not be interpreted by the XSLT processor and you do not have another declaration of `pass_js_variable` in your XSLT. You will have to declare it and pass it to the XSLT.

Comment: Any code that can declare the javascript variable to be passed to the XSL?